# Latter part of code somehow affecting former

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::vector<int> task_scores;
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int sc;
        std::cin >> sc;
        task_scores.push_back(sc);
    }
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<size_t>> student_solutions;
    std::string command = "";
    while(true) {
        std::vector<std::string> tok_com;
        getline(std::cin, command);
        std::stringstream strstream(command);
        std::string token = "";
        while (getline(strstream, token, ' ')) {
            std::cout << token;
            tok_com.push_back(token);
        }
        if (tok_com[0] == "SOLVED") {
            std::string name = tok_com[1];
            int task = std::stoi(tok_com[2]);
            if(std::find(student_solutions[name].begin(), student_solutions[name].end(), task) !=
               student_solutions[name].end()) {
                student_solutions[name].push_back(task);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you comment out if clause, then code works just fine. But if you don't, the code stops with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when trying to cout the token. How can this happen?

Comment: What does the debugger show you when you step through the code?

Comment: Are you sure you don't invoke UB in your `if`, as out of bound access (`tok_com[2]`)?

Comment: I must have written this comment 10 times this week;  Replace all of your vector accesses using `[ ]` with a call to `at()`.  Using `at()` will identify any issues with an out-of-bounds access on the vectors.   Using just `[ ]` will not do that, and instead will just (usually) seg faults on an index that's out of bounds.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: A segfault on such an access is _rare_. That's kinda the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But if you don't, the code stops with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when trying to cout the token. How can this happen?

```
if (tok_com[0] == "SOLVED") {
        // ^^^
```

requires that at least one value was actually stored into the `tok_com` vector within your loop before.

You should test for `tok_com.empty()` before dereferencing `tok_com`:

```
if (!tok_com.empty() && tok_com[0] == "SOLVED") {
 // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
    // ...
}
```

---

What you're experiencing actually is **undefined behavior** varying from *exploding fridges*, *little demons flying out from your nostrils* or simply exceptions thrown by your debugging environment or operating system.

Comment: @RomaValcer Well, undefined behavior is eehm _undefined_.

Comment: @RomaValcer -- Accessing a vector out-of-bounds using `[ ]` is undefined behavior.  If you really want to see a "crash" as soon as you make a mistake, do as my comment above stated, and that is to use `at()` instead of `[ ]`.

Comment: @RomaValcer You probably need a `cin.ignore` before the while loop to clear out any remaining whitespace after the last cin >> sc.